# UWP Image.Source binding with converter

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In my code I have a class with the following fields:

```
public class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...

    public string Path { get => $"/Assets/Images/{Name}.svg"; }
}
```

Path property is there just for debugging.

I also develop a converter in order to get rid of Path property.

```
public class SourceToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return $"/Assets/Images/{value}.svg";
    }
}
```

When I use Path property as Image Source, everything works fine, but when I try to do the same with the SourceToImageConverter, app is not working. 
I know converter is working as it Should cause when I use it on a TextBlock it shows the right value.
Xaml code looks like:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:SourceToImageConverter x:Key="SourceToImage"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SourceListViewTemplate" x:DataType="models:Source">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{x:Bind Path}"/>
            <Image Source="{x:Bind Name, Converter={StaticResource SourceToImage}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Converter={StaticResource SourceToImage}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

...

<GridView
    x:Name="Source"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Sources}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SourceListViewTemplate}"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    SelectionMode="Single"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlbindinghelper.convertvalue) to the value just as auto-generated {x:Bind} code is doing backstage.

```
public class SourceToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //if (targetType == typeof(string)) return $"/Assets/Images/{value}.svg";

        return XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(ImageSource), $"/Assets/Images/{value}.svg"); 
    }
}
```